How to measure angle using gerber viewer software
The working Gerber file I received for my design has been rotated to fit into a panel, but I don’t know the exact angle of rotation. I need to determine this angle by superimposing the original Gerber onto the rotated one. However, I can’t find a way to measure angles in View Mate. Does anyone know how to measure angles in View Mate, or is there another Gerber viewer software that can perform angle measurement?

Why can you not ask the company that sent you the working Gerbers how much they rotated it by?

Can you show us the panel? Usually the designs are rotated 0°/90°/180° or 270° to fit into a panel.

I would use a program called Meazure which allows you to measure objects on the computer screen. Using LordTeddy's example with Meazure shows the measured angle to be 45°.

If the rotation angle isn't simple to find due to an odd rotation angle, you can find a trace that you know should be zero degrees in the Gerber file (look at the text in the Gerber file, assuming you have a ASCII Gerber file) and use the endpoint coordinates to find the angle.

Kicad's Gerber viewer includes a measuring tool that includes an absolute angle for the measurement. Getting a rotation would be done by measuring the original, measuring the rotated, and subtracting one angle from another.

It's a bit awkward doing it this way, particularly as you can't snap the measurement to the track, but you should be able to do it.
Once you've installed kicad, open the gerber viewer. You want the auto import (red circle) to load gerber files, and then the measuring tool (blue circle). You may need to change the grid (yellow circle) to be fine enough to get a good measurement.

